# CURL with File content

Tags: java, unix

I created a WCF service which is HTTP Post that receives several parameters and does something. The Service is hosted on IIS server
The web service is launched from Unix within a Java code (Runtime.GetRunTime()...) using CURL command which is executed. The parameters are passed using -d option of CURL. 
Now one of the parameters should be a content of a file located in UNIX. I tried to do it, but the file contains specials chars which breaks my command (actually breaks the parameters of the CURL command). I tried to change this parameters in the service to receive the file location in UNIX. but the web server doesn't have access to this Unix location. 
Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Please show us your code which calls cURL and the command line as you would type it in your terminal. Why don't you use the cURL Java bindings? http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/java/

Comment: I use the following code Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

String[] commands = {"curl  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d '{“Comments“:”Hello”' http://julesserivce-int.iil.intel.com/JuleSService.svc/submit};

Process proc = rt.exec(commands);

Comment: But if i change "Hello" to something with specials chars e.g. " char . it breaks my command . The "Hello" should actually be a content of a UNIX file